# filter en change usage location for my all users - script powershell or Ms Graph

Tags: azure-powershell

create an MS Graph or powershell script that changes "usage location" of all users to "CA"

I was able to do it for one user but I want to do it for all users

```
$userId = '00000000000000'
$usageLocation = 'IN'

Update-MgUser -UserId $userId -Usagelocation $usageLocation
```

Answer (score 0):

> create an MS Graph or powershell script that changes "usage location"  of all users to "CA"

To update the users usage location to Canada using the Graph module, you can use the script below:

**Script**

```
Connect-MgGraph

# Get all users
$users = Get-MgUser -All 

# Update the usage location for each user
foreach ($user in $users) {
    Update-MgUser -UserId $user.Id -UsageLocation "CA"
}
```

The above script will connect to Microsoft Graph, get all users, and then update the usage location for each user to "CA" in my environment.

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Microsoft.Graph.Users Module | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/?view=graph-powershell-1.0)